# AJAX request body randomly empty on server side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a browser-based client that makes AJAX calls to a PHP/Apache back-end. When a button is clicked, the client loops through a list of "providers" and sends an Ajax request to each of them with *exactly* the same payload.

Randomly some of the requests in the loop are arriving at the server side with a blank POST body. What is really strange about this is the fact that other requests in the same loop are arriving properly populated. Sometimes we are seeing all of the items in the loop arriving with a blank body, sometimes some in the loop. It is really strange!

Environment details:

> Client = JQuery 3.3.1, JQueryUI 1.12.1, Bootstrap 3.3.7, JQuery validate 1.19.0
>
> Server = Apache 2.4, PHP 7.1

We cannot actually reproduce the problem in a development environment, but logging in production is clearly showing that this is happening regularly on a daily basis (maybe 5% of requests). We have deployed monitoring on the client browsers to trap any errors and there is nothing in terms of exceptions or anything that looks like it could be related.

The sample below shows what we are doing on the client side. 
1) bind a click event to 
2) when clicked, populate a request object
3) loop through the list of "providers", posting request from 2 to PHP server

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    bindEvents();
}

function bindEvents() {
    $("#myButton").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        handleClick();
    });
}

function handleClick() {
    var request = ...;
    ...
    var save=false;
    if (....) {
        save=true;
    }
    var providers = ["provider1", "provider2", "provider3", "provider4", "provider5", "provider6"];
    var ndx;
    for (ndx=0; ndx<providers.length; ++ndx) {
        doRequestSend("action/"+(save?"save":"verify"), request, providers[ndx]);
    }
}

function doRequestSend(action, request, provider) {
    request['apiKey']=getAPIKey();
    var url=baseURL+"/api/"+provider+"/"+action;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            ...
        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            ...
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously, it is difficult to figure out the issue when I cannot reproduce. However, am hoping the someone might spot a problem with the approach that could be resulting in the issue.

Alternatively, open to any random/crazy ideas that could explain HOW this could possibly be happening! Some requests in the loop arrive fine, others arrive blank!

Notes:
- Although the loop POST to a slightly different url with each iteration, on  the server side, they all end up at the same entry point and the first thing that is done is a log of the body (this is how we know it is blank!)
- The only browsers that (to date) seem to have experienced the issue are Chrome 73 & 74 on Windows. This might not be relevant!

Anyone got any ideas or things to try that might track down the source?
Cheers!

Comment: What I could think of, would be something like pressing the button twice very fast (which really happens in real life). You should try it and see if it's reproduced

Comment: Hi @Matei Mihai, thats a good suggestion, but unfortunately, its something we already tried. We couldn't seem to get it to reproduce the problem and we also tried disabling the button and unlinking the event handler after first click, but that didn't seem to offer a fix unfortunatley.

Comment: _“and the first thing that is done is a log of the body (this is how we know it is blank!)”_ - can you show what exactly you are doing on the receiving end? _How_ are you logging the request body content?

Comment: @04FS, certainly, simple as $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input'); if (strlen($requestBody < 1)) { ...LOG ERROR ...}

Comment: Hm, okay. So `request` is the same whenever this function is called, that is a static value/object/array, doesn’t change between requests, right? What about the target URL you are assembling here, `var url=baseURL+"/api/"+provider+"/"+action;` - could `provider` perhaps contain any special characters, that could make the URL invalid somehow, or pointing to somewhere else than actually intended? If so, I’d try to properly URL-encode that value before it gets inserted into the URL (`encodeURIComponent` should do)

Comment: Maybe try and log the request method also, when you determined that the request body was empty - if the URL was invalid/wrong somehow, maybe some server-side rewriting tries to “correct” that via an external redirect - and depending on the status code, the client could follow that redirect by making a GET request instead of a POST, in which case `php://input` should be empty.

Comment: Follow-up thought. I found a way to simulate the issue. Dont know if this is *actually* what is happening, but it does cause the same behaviour. Basically if I manually corrupt the JSON string by posting "X" + JSON.stringify(request) I see the bad string being posted (in browser network console) and then on the server side, php://input is blank. So if the JSON was getting corrupted somehow, this could explain what is happening. Not yet sure how to trap the 'raw' bad request on the server side to actually diagnose further....investigation on-going!

Comment: @04FS, some good suggestions. Yes, you are 100% correct, the 'request' is generated outside the post loop and never changed within the loop, so same request being sent each time. As regards the 'provider' this is not a dynamic list, its a fixed list of 6 simple lowercase alpha names that is 'hard coded' into the JS, so no chance of there being something unusual happening on the URL.

Comment: Do you have full control over the web server? If so, I’d try to enable https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_logio.html and have it log the number of received bytes. (That is headers and body combined, but if you log the headers as well from your PHP script, maybe you can calculate the difference.) That way you could try and determine if no post body way received by the web server to begin with, or if it gets lost afterwards when the whole thing gets passed over to PHP.

Comment: @04FS, great suggestion. Going to do that now.

Comment: @04FS, that suggested gave a good lead. Bytes in are broadly the same, so it must be PHP that is stripping / consuming the malformed data.....investigating......!!